# How to show command addBox using button in the same frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a `NoteBook` containing `Tabs`. One the these `Tabs` contains a `Button` that when clicked creates an `EditText` with this line of code

```
btn1 = ttk.Button(page1, text = "Add Site Code", command=addBox)
```

The problem is when I click this `button` it creates the `EditText` outside the frame like this
[image: screenshot]

I need to show the `EditText` below the button inside the frame

However this is my code

```
from tkinter import  *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import background as background
#------------------------------------

def addBox():
    print ("ADD")

    ent = Entry(root)
    ent.pack()

    all_entries.append( ent )

#------------------------------------

all_entries = []

root = Tk()
root.title('Notebook Demo')
# set the configuration of GUI window
w = 600
h = 400
sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (sw - w) / 2
y = (sh - h) / 2
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.config(background = '#A9A9A9')

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
#nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='RDT & On-Air')
nb.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")

page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page2, text='Existing Sites')
nb.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")

page3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page3, text='All Data')
nb.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")

btn1 = ttk.Button(page1, text = "Add Site Code", command=addBox)
btn1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You give `root` as the master of your entries so they are packed below your Notebook. If you want to put them in the frame, give the frame as master when you create your entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add the new `Entry` having `root` as a parent at line 9:

```py
ent = Entry(root)
```

You should use the actual frame you want the entry to be in as a parent widget. Substitute `root` with `page1`

```py
def addBox():
    print ("ADD")

    ent = Entry(page1)
    ent.pack()

    all_entries.append( ent )
```